# Error with left hand side of assignment expression Angular 2+

Tags: angular, filter

I am currently trying to filter my JSON that is returned from hard-coded data. In my component my code currently looks like this:

```
export class CtaComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() ctaId: string;

  public ctaCards: CtaCards.ICtaCard[];
  constructor(private ctaService: CtaService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.ctaId !== undefined) {
      this.ctaService.getCtaCards(this.ctaId)
        .subscribe(x => {
          this.ctaCards.find(z => z.id == this.ctaId) = x
        })
    }
  }
}
```

As I am sure you can see, the line with `find` is not working. The `ctaId` is the id used to filter against the `JSON` id. However the code by `find` is highlighted as an error and says that `The left hand-side assignment expression must be a variable or property access.` I am quite new to Angular so this might just be something glaringly wrong. Nothing I have researched has seem to help me.

My service looks like this:

```
export class CtaService {
  private ctaCard: BehaviorSubject<CtaCards.ICtaCard[]>
  private productUrl = 'src/assets/cta.json'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getCtaCards(id: string): BehaviorSubject<CtaCards.ICtaCard[]{
    if (id) {
      this.ctaCard = new BehaviorSubject<CtaCards.ICtaCard[]>(null);

      this.http.get(this.productUrl).pipe(
        retry(3)
      )
        .subscribe((x: CtaCards.ICtaCard[]) => this.ctaCard.next(x))
    }
    return this.ctaCard;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `z` here?

Comment: @HarunurRashid it is the `Cta card` so in this case it is getting the `id` of the `Cta Card`.

Comment: @FrankFajardo it does use it later on, that check at the start is just for checking.

Comment: This code does not make sense: `this.ctaCards.find(z => z.id == this.ctaId) = x`. I think you meant `this.ctaCards.find(z => z.id == this.ctaId) == x` or `this.ctaCards.find(z => z.id == this.ctaId) === x`. But then again, that is a logical check. What comes after that?

Comment: @FrankFajardo you are correct, I will go re-evaluate my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find some `ctaCard` and assign `x` to it. You can not do that because,

The [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns:

The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function; otherwise, undefined is returned.
 And you can not assign something in value rather than variable. You are trying to do something like this:

```
var a = 5;
5 = 10;
```

Which makes no sense.

You can rather use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) as below:

```
index = this.ctaCards.findIndex(z => z.id == this.ctaId);
this.ctaCards[index] = x;
```

Comment: That does make sense, do you have a suggestion as to how I can fix my code?

Comment: Updated my answer. You can fix your code by last two line of code

Comment: @DanielBailey, please let me know if it works for you .. ? For more reference, you can read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/

Comment: Don't forget to handle exception. index can be -1, when no data found :)